# Executing Python Program from an Android Smart Device using SSH

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, raspberry-pi, jsch

I am trying to execute a Python Program (which is running on my Raspberry Pi) remotely from an Android Phone via SSH.
On the Android-Side I am using the JSch library and basically the code explained here:
http://droid-lernen.de/raspberry-pi-mit-dem-smartphone-steuern-teil-1/

On the Raspberry side I am trying to run a simple program in python, creating a PDF with some plots (using matplotlib library).

I have managed to establish a connection, but starting the program via the Android App doesn't work properly. The program starts, but can't finish. If I start the program manually on the Raspberry ("sudo python myprogram.py"), it just works fine.

I guess there are some privileges issues, but my research didn't give any results.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean it can't finish? does it run forever, or exits without completing the job it was supposed to?

Comment: It exits without completing the job. It creates a corrupted PDF, if one with the same name doesn't exist, or it can't overwrite the old one.

Comment: do you end the ssh connection before the script has had a chance to finish?

Answer (score 0):

When you SSH into a linux box, it creates a new process for the SSH. All processes you run from the terminal run as child processes of the SSH process you established. If the SSH process is terminated, the OS will send a Hangup signal to all the children of the SSH process, and this will cause those process to exit immediately.

Use `nohup` when executing your script from the SSH process. This will cause the child process to ignore the hangup signal and continue running

`nohup python my_script.py`

Comment: Thank you for the information. It sounds logically and I've tried to use the "nohup" command, but it didn't work. We have localized the problem, when we create an empty PDF File, it works with the sudo command, but if we try to put some plots on it, it interrupts the program and creates a corrupted PDF file. Really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happens because you send an sudo command and your Raspberry Pi is expecting an password.

Try to use a command like this: `echo <password> | sudo -S python myprogram.py`.

You can also ask the author of this article. Maybe he can give you an more dedicated answer.